# Yarp on docker https between containers

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose, https, ssl-certificate

I'm attempting to deploy a .NET Core API Gateway on Docker using Yarp ReverseProxy (although I believe this detail may not be relevant). The services are accessible from the outside using HTTPS and from the API Gateway container using HTTP.

The issue arises when I attempt to forward the HTTPS requests through the API Gateway. I encounter an SSL error, and I suspect that the problem is related to the "CN=localhost" on the dev-certs generated by Visual Studio.

I also tried setting up a self-signed PFX with "CN=mymicroservicename," but I am still encountering the error.

The certificate is linked to the container using a volume bind, and I can confirm its presence when exploring the container. The services are part of the same network, which seems evident as I can use telnet to connect to the service from the API Gateway using the service name. Despite these configurations, the issue persists.

```
Yarp.ReverseProxy.Forwarder.HttpForwarder[9]
      Proxying to https://myservicename:8081/authentication/login HTTP/2 RequestVersionOrLower 
warn: Yarp.ReverseProxy.Forwarder.HttpForwarder[48]
      Request: An error was encountered before receiving a response.
      System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
       ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch, RemoteCertificateChainErrors
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ReadOnlySpan`1 alert, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp2ConnectionAsync(QueueItem queueItem)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Yarp.ReverseProxy.Forwarder.HttpForwarder.SendAsync(HttpContext context, String destinationPrefix, HttpMessageInvoker httpClient, ForwarderRequestConfig requestConfig, HttpTransformer transformer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

The selfsigned certificate properties are

```
CN=myservicename
DNS NAME = myservicename
Key Usage = Digital Signature, Key Encipherment (a0)
```

I am also forcing Kestrel to use the SelfSigned Certificate with the following code.

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(opt =>
{
    opt.ListenAnyIP(8080);
    opt.ListenAnyIP(8081, listOpt =>
    {
        listOpt.UseHttps(builder.Configuration["CertPath"], builder.Configuration["CertPassword"]);
    });
});
```

Comment: I have solved by extracting the .crt from the .pfx (inside the container) moved the crt to /usr/local/share/ca-certificates and trusting it running update-ca-certificates.